# How do I code a proper footer with link to profile center?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, preference-center

My html email template was originally coded for internal organization communications. It was designed and built in SF Marketing Cloud and delivered via Outlook. As such it was created without a footer. We are now sending this externally and I have added a footer, including the href %%profile_center_url%%. When attempting to preview and test, I get the following message: "A profile center link is missing from this email. For template based email, please contact our customer service."

Have I missed the entry of a variable somewhere? Everything I am reading has stated I need this code and nothing more. Or is it possible I am using an incorrect send classification? I am stumped.

Comment: Have you checked on the plain text version in your email that it already includes the part `%%profile_center_url%%`?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the Profile Link Check through:

**Setup > Email Optional Features > Disable Profile Link Check checkbox.**

Don't forget that:

> Turning this feature off removes the requirement for the Profile
> Center link when validating and sending emails. Ensure your emails
> meet local regulatory requirements before disabling this feature.

More about the Profile Center here:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_profile_center.htm&type=5